# Ignore unwanted columns using CSVBeanReader

Tags: java, supercsv

I hope the kind people here can help me with my CSV situation. I only need to read the first 3 columns in the CSV that i'm using. I have no control in the number of columns that the CSV file has and there are no headers available. I tried using the partial read with CSVBeanReader (https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_partial_reading.html) but I keep getting the "nameMapping array and the number of columns read" error. I would like to ask if the partial reading example works for the supercsv version 2.4.0 which i'm currently using.  See below the code I used which I patterned similar to the partial read example

```
public class MainPartialRead {

public void partialRead() throws Exception {
    ICsvBeanReader beanReader = null;
    String csv_filename = "test2.csv";
    try {
        beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(csv_filename), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
        beanReader.getHeader(true); // skip past the header (we're defining our own)
        System.out.println("beanreader Length: " + beanReader.length());

        // only map the first 3 columns - setting header elements to null means those columns are ignored
        final String[] header = new String[]{"column1", "column2", "column3", null, null, null, null, null,
            null, null};

        // no processing required for ignored columns
        final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[]{new NotNull(), new NotNull(),
            new NotNull(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null};

        beanCSVReport customer;
        while ((customer = beanReader.read(beanCSVReport.class, header, processors)) != null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("lineNo=%s, rowNo=%s, customer=%s", beanReader.getLineNumber(),
                    beanReader.getRowNumber(), customer));
        }
    } finally {
        if (beanReader != null) {
            beanReader.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the sample CSV file i'm using:

```
466,24127,abc,53516
868,46363,hth,249
```

Comment: where are the headers in the sample csv?

Comment: sad to say there are no headers.

Answer (score 1):

you did not mention the complete error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the nameMapping array and the number of columns read should be the same size
(nameMapping length = 10, columns = 4)
```

From this it is very clear what the issue is. You have just 4 columns in the csv file but you have mentioned mapping for 10 columns, 7 of them null.

Removing 6 nulls from header and processors fixes the issue.

another point to note. The following code skips the first line assuming it to be header as you instructed but in fact it is not a header row. You should not call this method.

```
beanReader.getHeader(true);
```

Comment: yes, you are correct in your observation in the header mapping in the code and thank you for pointing out the behavior of beanReader.getHeader. I am more interested to know if the partial read example available in the superCSV site (see link in my question) works as presented in their site. My attempts to replicate the example have failed as shown in the code I presented. I need to read only the first 3 columns of my CSV file which may have any number of columns and disregard the rest. I also need to have processors parse those 3 columns to ensure validity. Thanks!

Comment: As I said in my response, the partial reading works by putting in the right number of nulls. You have 7 nulls. Replace the same with 1 null. 3 named columns and 1 null (ignored) column. It works. Now if your question is that you do not even know the number of columns, then you need to read one line and figure that out. In the column mapping pass right number of columns, named or null. I have run your sample and it works.